# Interpreting a hazard ratio for time-dependent coefficients

Tags: survival, interaction, cox-model, time-varying-covariate

I have a cox model with two main effects (x,y) and two interaction terms (x*t, y*t) where t is time. I am having some trouble interpreting the hazard ratios. Does the hazard ration become more of an instantaneous hazard rate when you have time-dependent coefficients in the model?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please say more about what you mean by the interaction terms with time and how you are representing them to the survival-analysis software? That’s a potential source of error as explained in [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) on pages 19-20. Depending on what you mean by the interactions with time it might be impossible to interpret the hazard ratios in a useful way.

Comment: Notwithstanding the previous comment, there will not be *one* HR (unless the interaction effect = 0), the HR will depend on the time, HR(x,t) = h(x+1,t)/h(x,t)